# FluentValidation failure not returning BadRequest

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have wired up FluentValidation as per instructions, and when debuging test I can see that model is invalid based on the test setup, but exception is not thrown, but rather method on the controller is being executed. This is on 3.1 with EndPoint routing enabled. Is there anything else one needs to do to get this to work and throw. What happens is that validation obviously runs; it shows as ModelState invalid and correct InstallmentId is invalid, but it keeps processing in Controller instead of throwing exception.

```
services.AddMvc(
                    options =>
                    {
                         options.EnableEndpointRouting = true;
                         //// options.Filters.Add<ExceptionFilter>();
                         //// options.Filters.Add<CustomerRequestFilter>();
                     })
                    .AddFluentValidation(
                         config =>
                         {
                            config.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
                         })
```

**Command and Validator**

```
     public class ProcessManualPayment
        {
            public class Command
                : CustomerRequest<Result?>
            {
                public Guid PaymentPlanId { get; set; }
    
                public Guid InstallmentId { get; set; }
    
                public Guid PaymentCardId { get; set; }
            }
    
          
            public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Command>
            {
                public Validator()
                {
                    this.RuleFor(x => x.CustomerId)
                        .IsValidGuid();
    
                    this.RuleFor(x => x.PaymentPlanId)
                        .IsValidGuid();
    
                    this.RuleFor(x => x.InstallmentId)
                        .IsValidGuid();
    
                    this.RuleFor(x => x.PaymentCardId)
                        .IsValidGuid();
                }
            }
```

**Controller**

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("payments")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessManualPayment(
           [FromBody]
            ProcessManualPayment.Command command)
    {
```

**Test**

```
            [Fact]
            public async Task When_Command_Has_Invalid_Payload_Should_Fail()
            {
                var client = this.factory.CreateClient();

                // Arrange
                var validCmd = new ProcessManualPayment.Command()
                {
                    CustomerId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    PaymentPlanId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    InstallmentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    PaymentCardId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                };

                var validCmdJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(validCmd, Formatting.None);

                var jObject = JObject.Parse(validCmdJson);

                jObject["installmentId"] = "asdf";

                var payload = jObject.ToString(Formatting.None);

                // Act
                var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);

                var response = await client.PostAsync(MakePaymentUrl, content);

                var returned = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            [Fact]
            public async Task When_Payload_Is_Null_Should_Fail()
            {
                // Arrange
                var client = this.factory.CreateClient();

                // Act
                var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(MakePaymentUrl, null);

                // Assert
                response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
```

**GuidValidator**

```
    public class GuidValidator : PropertyValidator
    {
        public GuidValidator()
            : base("'{PropertyName}' value {AttemptedValue} is not a valid Guid.")
        {
        }

        protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
        {
            context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("AttemptedValue", context.PropertyValue ?? "'null'");

            if (context.PropertyValue == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            Guid.TryParse(context.PropertyValue.ToString(), out var value);

            return IsValid(value);
        }

        private static bool IsValid(Guid? value) =>
            value.HasValue
            && !value.Equals(Guid.Empty);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Mystery solved, I was missing `[ApiController]` attribute on the controller.